# Do exec() calls fork for each command if passed a shell script?

Tags: c, shell, sh, exec, strace

For each command in a shell script passed to exec(), is it forked and ran in a child process?
Say I have a shell script called test.sh with the following contents;

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello
echo There
```

What I want to know is how the series of commands is treated if I were to call execvp() on test.sh in a C program.

For each command within the script, is there a fork followed by another exec call on that command, before a return to the parent and a repeat for the next command?

So far I have used strace on this exact example. My findings are that if I put two echos into the script, there are no calls to clone() (which I believe equates to forking?), but if I put two separate cats as such:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat file1
cat file2
```

Then I find two calls to clone in the strace. At the same time, stracing a singular cat call on its own, without running it from an execvp call on a shell script, does not yield any clones in the strace.

I would really appreciate a clarification on the way which exec calls handle shell scripts.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with exec(). echo is usually a builtin, so there is no reason for the shell to fork. And some shells replace themselves with the last command to be executed in a script if forking is unnecessary

Comment: `execvp()` itself will never fork and (unless it fails to start the program) will never return. It permanently gives up control of the process to a different program, and that program can in turn do whatever it wants, such as clone.

Answer (score 2):

The bash shell has a number of *built-in commands* that are executed in the same process as the shell.  The `echo` command is one of those built in commands.

`cat` on the other hand is at external program, so the shell must `fork` and `exec` to create a process and run the program.

Answer (score 1):

Some commands are built into the shell, so they don't need to fork. All the commands that implement control flow (e.g. `if`, `while`, `case`) have to be built in. So do the commands that change the shell process's state, such as `cd` and `ulimit`.

In addition, a number of simple commands are implemented as shell built-ins; these include `echo` and `printf`. So you won't see any forks in the first script with two `echo` commands.

The `type` command (itself a built-in) can be used to show which commands are built-ins. For example, `type echo` reports `echo is a shell builtin`, but `type cat` reports `cat is /bin/cat`.

Finally, the exit status of a script is the same as the exit status of the last command. So as an optimization, it doesn't fork for the last command, it simply execs it. That's why you see forks when the script has two `cat` commands, but not when there's only one.